# Why does conversion to reference interfere with conversion to bool?

Tags: c++

It seems that if I have a conversion operator to a reference, this operator will take precedence over a conversion to a `bool`. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

(If it matters, I am using GCC 4.5. I verified on ideone that the same behavior is found with GCC-4.7.2.)

Assume the following:

```
class B {
protected:
    const int a_;
    int b_;
    B (int b, int a) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
public:
    operator bool () const { return b_ == a_; }
};

class D1 : public B {
public:
    D1 (int b = 0, int a = 0) : B(b, a) {}
    operator int () const { return b_; }
};

class D2 : public B {
public:
    D2 (int b = 0, int a = 0) : B(b, a) {}
    operator int & () { return b_; }
};
```

Then, assume they are used in a simple program like this:

```
int main () {
    if (D1 d1a = D1('a', 'a')) std::cout << "d1a\n";
    if (D1 d1b = D1('b', 'a')) std::cout << "d1b\n";
    if (D2 d2a = D2('a', 'a')) std::cout << "d2a\n";
    if (D2 d2b = D2('b', 'a')) std::cout << "d2b\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
d1a
d2a
d2b
```

Note that `d1b` is not in the output, which means the conversion to `bool` worked the way I expected it to for `D1`. But, for `D2`, it seems the conversion to the reference type took precedence over the `bool` conversion. Why did this happen? Is there a simple change I can make to `D2` to allow the `bool` conversion to take precedence in the `if` check?

Currently, I am using `D1` and adding an assignment operator to it to achieve the behavior of a reference.

Comment: Well yes, I agree I probably should have been able to spot this myself, but is there a more substantial reason for the down vote other than punishing me for me having a bad day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it has nothing to do with `int&`, it's a matter of `const`-ness:

```
operator bool () const { return b_ == a_; }
              /* ^^^^^ */
              /* vvvvv */
operator int & () { return b_; }
```

`d2a` is a `D2`, not a `const D2`, so the non-const conversion operator is a better fit. If you write it as

```
operator const int & () const { return b_; }
```

you will get the expected behaviour, see http://ideone.com/vPPPYV.

Note that `operator const int&` won't interfere even if you use the `const` versions of your objects, the following lines would still result in your expected behaviour (see http://ideone.com/DTE0xH):

```
if (const D1 d1a = D1('a', 'a')) std::cout << "d1a\n";
if (const D1 d1b = D1('b', 'a')) std::cout << "d1b\n";
if (const D2 d2a = D2('a', 'a')) std::cout << "d2a\n";
if (const D2 d2b = D2('b', 'a')) std::cout << "d2b\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it for me. The fix is to add a non-`const` version of the `bool` conversion operator.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
D1 d1a = D1('a', 'a');
D1 d1b = D1('b', 'a');
D2 d2a = D2('a', 'a');
D2 d2b = D2('b', 'a');
if (d1a) std::cout << "d1a\n";
if (d1b) std::cout << "d1b\n";
if (d2a) std::cout << "d2a\n";
if (d2b) std::cout << "d2b\n";
```

prints

```
d1a
d2a
```

for me.

You have

```
if (D2 d2a = D2('a', 'a')) std::cout << "d2a\n";
if (D2 d2a = D2('b', 'a')) std::cout << "d2b\n";
```

What happens if you don't use the same name in both cases?
There's only `d1a` and `d2a` in the output if I replace the 4th if by

```
if (D2 d2b = D2('b', 'a')) std::cout << "d2b\n";
```

Comment: The result is the same (see http://ideone.com/CpPXZS). I will update the question.

Comment: Ok, well ... MSVC++11 (VS12) does not print `d2b`.

Comment: +1, I find the difference in behavior between GCC-C++ and MSVC++ interesting.

Comment: It is really interesting that GCC seems to prefer the _better_ "direct overload resolution" yielding a conversion sequence over another conversion function that provides an exact match with a deviant cv-qualifier... :)